# Displaying comments per post on the home page

Tags: python, django

I want to display number of comments on blog home page where all post is showing up. I want to show number of comments on little comment icon under every post is having.

Models:

```py
class BlogPost(models.Model):

        sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=False)
        body = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=False, blank=False)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=False, blank=True)
        date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date_published")
        date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="date_updated")
        author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORIES_NAME, default='Entertainment')
        slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


class BlogComment(models.Model):
    
        sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        comment = models.TextField()
        user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.sno)
```

Homepage view:

```py
BLOG_POSTS_PER_PAGE = 4


def home_screen_view(request):
    
    context = {}

    query = ""

    if request.GET:
        query = request.GET.get('q', '')
        context['query'] = str(query)
    blog_posts = sorted(get_blog_queryset(query), key=attrgetter('date_updated'), reverse=True)
    comments = BlogComment.objects.all()

    # Pagination
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    blog_posts_paginator = Paginator(blog_posts, BLOG_POSTS_PER_PAGE)

    try:
        blog_posts =blog_posts_paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        blog_posts =blog_posts_paginator.page(BLOG_POSTS_PER_PAGE)
    except EmptyPage:
        blog_posts =blog_posts_paginator.page(blog_posts_paginator.num_pages)
        
    context['blog_posts'] = blog_posts
    context['comments'] = comments
    return render(request, "personal/home.html", context)
```

Comment: Please post the code of `personal/home.html` template.

Comment: Could you do something like `{{ blogpost.comments.count }}` on the template?

Comment: im getting all the comments displayed here related to the post after using Aggregation Count. i have updated my views.py file below please have a look. when im trying to enter {{ comment.comment.count}} its throwing this error "no signature found for builtin <built-in method count of str object at 0x00000135AE4CFF70>".